# Blazor webassembly quick opening a new tab

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I develop a Blazor Wasm application and I noticed that opening a new tab (Ctrl + click) is slow, probably because a new instance of webassembly is being downloaded. Is there any way to quickly open a new tab? Maybe there is some sort of caching I don't aware of. Because as far as I can understand it can be possible to use same downloaded binary for a new tabs, but I'm a newbie in webassembly technology so maybe it's just not possible for some reason.